# Qt: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I'm trying to connect a signal from a `QProcess` inside my `mainwindow()` object to another `QObject` based class inside my `mainwindow()` object but I get this error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::readyReadStandardOutput () to (null)::logReady()
```

Heres the code, its not complete by any means but I don't know why it doesn't work.

exeProcess.h

```
#ifndef EXEPROCESS_H
#define EXEPROCESS_H

#include <QObject>


class exeProcess : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit exeProcess(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void outLog(QString outLogVar); //will eventually connect to QTextEdit

public slots:
    void logReady();

};

#endif // EXEPROCESS_H
```

exeProcess.cpp

```
#include "exeprocess.h"

exeProcess::exeProcess(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void exeProcess::logReady(){
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>

#include "exeprocess.h"

/*main window ---------------------------------------*/

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QProcess *proc;
    exeProcess *procLog;


public slots:


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};




#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput ()), procLog, SLOT(logReady()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Thanks!.

Comment: I don't know what compiler or flags you're using, but you're lucky they were even null.  It would have been a lot harder to figure out had they been some random memory addresses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create the `proc` and `procLog` objects.

You've only got pointers as class members, so you'll have to initialize those (with `new`). `connect` only works on live objects.

Comment: got it, as you may have guessed im new to stackoverflow, in terms of etiquette should i go for asking each new question in a new thread or just follow up with related questions in the same thread.

Comment: @jonathon make a new thread on stackoverflow for each question :)

Answer (score 1):

proc is a pointer, but it does not point to anything. You have to instantiate a qprocess before you connect it!

```
proc = new QProcess();
connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput ()), procLog, SLOT(logReady()));
```